# Combine list of videos into one video

Tags: python, list, video, movie

I have a list of videos (all `.mp4`), that I would like to combine to one large `.mp4` video. The names of the files are as following: `vid0.mp4`, `vid1.mp4`, `vid2.mp4`, .... After searching, I found [a Quora question](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-join-10-small-videos-30-sec-each-using-Python-into-1-video-I-need-to-automate-it-as-I-have-3000+-types-of-these-videos-I-have-to-combine) which explains that the main file should be opened, then all sub files should be read (as bits) and then written. So here is my code:

```
import os
with open("MainVideo.mp4","wb") as f:
    for video in os.listdir("/home/timmy/sd/videos/"):
        temp=open('/home/timmy/sd/videos/%s'%video)
        h=temp.read()
        '''
        for i in h:
            f.write(i) #Error

        '''
        f.write(h)
        temp.close()
```

This is only writing the first video. Is there a way to write it without using outside libraries? If not, please refer me to one.

I also tried the `moviepy` library but I get `OSError`.

code:

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
li1=[]
for i in range(0,30):
    name_of_file = "/home/timmy/sd/videos/vid%d.mp4"%i
    clip = VideoFileClip(name_of_file)
    #print(name_of_file)
    li1.append(clip)
```

I get `OSError` after the 9th clip. (I think this is because of the size of the list.)

Comment: I suggest you use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) `concat` which I think is more efficient.

Comment: @SenDjasni Do you mean to use it with `subprocess`?

Comment: Yes. Or `os.system(ffmpeg_command))`